# Filtering out deleted results before returning output to user JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter, sequelize.js

Before returning the output from my server, I'm trying to filter out all of the deleted parts.

The structure of my schema can be described as follows:

```
results: 
   - result: 
       -item: 
          -itemReservations: 
               -reservationPart: 
                   -isDeleted: true
               -reservationPart: 
                   -isDeleted: false
               -reservationPart: 
                   -isDeleted: false
```

I added the below code, however the output returned still contains results where `part.isDeleted` is `true`.

```
...
.then(results =>
    results.map(result => {
      if (result.item.itemReservations.length > 0) {
        result.item.itemReservations.map(
          itemReservation => {
            itemReservation.reservationParts = itemReservation.reservationParts.filter(
              part => !part.isDeleted
            );
            return itemReservation;
          }
        );
      }
      return result;
    })
  ).then(filteredResults => ...)
```

Comment: Can you replace your schema with a valid shaped object, so it would be faster for people to code on top of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was specific to `sequelize.js` - `result` was a sequelize object, not a json object:

Adding

`const jsonResult = result.toJSON();`

solved the issue.

Correct code:

```
.then(results =>
    results.map(result => {
      const jsonResult = result.toJSON();
        jsonResult.item.itemReservations.map(
          itemReservation => {
            itemReservation.reservationParts = itemReservation.reservationParts.filter(
              part => !part.isDeleted
            );
            return itemReservation;
          }
        );
      return jsonResult;
    })
  ).then(filteredResults => ...)
```

Also, as suggested by another answer - `if (result.item.itemReservations.length > 0)` is useless. `[].map(...)` returns `[]`